# Routinely Back Up Single Windows XP Folder to Network Drive

Tags: windows-xp, batch, batch-file, windows-server-2012

The company I'm at is using a piece of hardware running with a Windows XP program called OldXpProg. Looks to me like the program has hard-coded C:\OldXpProg... callouts throughout it (installs outside \Program Files), so I'm not going to risk trying to install it elsewhere. It saves and routinely updates a whole bunch of .config, .ini, custom file types, etc. for the hardware settings to its directory, and I want the whole directory (about 160MB) auto-backed up to our network drive once every 1-3 months or so. I don't care about anything else on this Windows XP machine except the single directory.

I think a BAT script on the XP machine that runs at system start-up will handle this, haven't tried that before, but are there any built-in processes that are cleaner?

Comment: Does your XP machine connect to your network to share files?  XP may not connect to modern networks which is why I ask.

Comment: @John Thanks; yeah, it maps the network location I want to a location drive without issue.

Comment: It's been a while since I used the Windows Task Scheduler on XP, so I don't recall whether it's able to trigger events at the required interval, but if you trigger a bat file that calls either XCOPY or (if XP has it or it's installable) ROBOCOPY, either one of those can back up your directory and in fact, back up only the files that have changed, so it'd be a fairly lightweight operation. If the PC runs constantly, you can have the backup trigger in the middle of the night so it doesn't affect normal operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *so I'm not going to risk trying to install it elsewhere. It saves and routinely updates a whole bunch of .config, .ini, custom file types, etc. for the hardware settings to its directory, and I want the whole directory (about 160MB) auto-backed up to our network drive once every 1-3 months or so.*

I suggest making use of a tool that allows the monitored execution of your folders/files backup.

And take advantage of additional features that will serve you well.

**[Cobian Backup](https://www.cobiansoft.com/cobianbackup.html)** was one I used a lot on Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 systems

**Obs.:** ***Cobian Backup** and **Cobian Reflector** are freeware and can be used for free even in a commercial environment.*